# ASP.NET MVC embed views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET & MVC (not programming though). Watching videos and getting up to speed. I mostly come from the desktop world and so I'm not a big fan of post backs. Naturally then I gravitate towards ajax.

In the MVC it seems in our controllers we generally do post backs to a View (html page). **My question is, could we embed views into 1 master view?** The idea being every request will be an ajax call to a controller, which will figure out what view it needs to return as html content to be embeded into the existing page. Resulting in no post backs and a more fluid user experience because of all the cool visual client side tricks we could do with the returned view via javascript. Think morphing, fading, sliding, etc.

As a user I would love to click a link, have the page fade away, and then fade in with the entire new page.

I'm probably showing my ignorance being new to this space, but this seems very possible.

Comment: Check out single page applications ASP.NET SPA. Or typically w would use ajax to avoid full postbacks.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I've heard people say before that problems are common when returning HTML to be rendered from an ajax call. Maybe SPA takes care of those problems.

Comment: Well a SPA is exactly what you are describing me thinks.

Comment: I'll chime in that SPAs are generally a bad idea for content-heavy websites (as opposed to web *applications*) because unless you handle history state, have graceful degredation, and correctly return "inner content" in response to a stateless GET request you'll run into problems. Just be careful. Don't forget to gracefully handle situations where Ajax requests fail (and they do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there is no concept of Postback in MVC. That is a Web Forms strategy of passing data to a server. Controller does not do any postback to view. What you have to understand is that controller is in charge of, lets say, preparing the information. This information is passed to a view to be presented in a way that View finds it fit. The controller returns a result and says which view should be used in order to satisfy user's request.

Users can submit data from the client using forms in a view to an action in some controller. Controller receives the information, processes it in a specific way and does something with it, like storing it in some data source. This is not a concept of postback like in Web forms.

What you described in your question is a way SPA application works, but you have to understand that even in SPA application the views are not always preloaded. This is true especially if you have a large application.

Downloading views, actually partial views, via Ajax is perfectly normal so it is not something that you should avoid at all cost. Later when you fetch a view via Ajax you can apply jQuery filters and special effects.

UPDATE: Controllers return action results. The base class for these results is, as you my have guessed `ActionResult`. Many other classes inherit from this class. For example, `ViewResult` is the most often used and is the subject of this answer. You also have `FileResult` that you use to return files, `RedirectToRouteResult` to perform redirection, and so on. All these are action result. Returning a view in MVC means: "In order to display this data to a user, please use this view or partial view."

When you request (issue HTTP GET method), a controller will return a view to you, and when you post data (issue HTTP POST method) a controller will do something and can perform redirection after which it normally returns a view, or return a file, etc. Postback in MVC in essence does not exist. For example, in Web Forms if you click on a button or change a value in a drop down box that has `AutoPostBack` set to `true`, the post back is initiated and the `ViewState` is sent to the server. MVC does not have that sort of mechanism to trigger postback. You either submit a form or use Ajax to perform GET request to retrieve information or POST to submit data as JSON back to the server.

So, when you make a request to see the page it is not a postback. When you post form data to the server it is not a postback, it is submitting the data and is not the same as Web Forms postback.

I hope this helps you now.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but generally the end result of a Controller is to show a view and the act of showing a view sends a new page to the browser which is basically a post back, ie visible loading of the page by the browser. I guess that's what I was trying to say/avoid.

Comment: Please see my update in the answer. I hope I helped you better understand MVC.

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to do this but *thank you* @HuseinRoncevic for this answer. This is the best explanation I've read so far about how MVC works!!